# Can I check for the existence of an HTTP only cookie with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, servicestack, single-page-application

Can I use Javascript to see if an HTTP-only cookie *exists*, I don't want to see the value, just know whether or not it is there.

I need this because I have an API using cookie based authentication with servicestack, with a client side SPA. I need to know, client side, whether or not I am authenticated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

HTTP-only cookies are not exposed to the JS in any way. That is the *point* of the HTTP-only flag.